# parseFloat acts weird when adding decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, parsefloat

[image]

Adding `parseFloat(33.3) + 37.4` gives `70.699999999` in chrome console

Can anyone explain me why this is happening and how to overcome this problem.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `parseFloat` - just how computers handle floats!  Try it yourself by adding `0.1 + 0.2`.

Comment: So how to overcome this issue. How do I round it to the correct number

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to round up to a specified number of decimals:

```
(33.3 + 37.4).toFixed(3); // would result in 70.700
```